# New to OpenGL code compiles but nothing happens?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, eclipse-cdt

I am having a ton of trouble getting my openGL configured, I am
currently using freeglut, windows 7, eclipse 64-bit, and MinGW. When I run the program no errors occur; however, no window pops up. I was curious of a few things:

- Has anyone ever experienced this issue before and what did you do to solve it (if any)?
- What IDE do you guys use to compile your OpenGL code I am willing to make the switch. any tutorials would be great for configurations.

These are the directions I follow: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/HowTo_OpenGL_C.html[2]

Comment: have you run it through a debugger or added some `cout` statements to see where it is going wrong?

Comment: Oddly enough I have added some cout statements and those don't even show up. The code just terminates (no errors , or anything noticible)

Comment: On IDEs : Visual Studio (Win), XCode (OS X), CodeBlocks (Linux)

Answer (score 3):

I found an article concerning your issue [here](http://riccardotramma.com/2011/04/setup-eclipse-to-develop-opengl-glut-apps-in-java-cc-on-windows-mac/). [Getting started with OpenGL in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461476/getting-started-with-opengl-in-c) might also help. Though, just in case, here's another example to test:

```
void init() {
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glClearDepth(1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void display() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

  glPushMatrix();
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glutSolidTeapot(2.5);
  glPopMatrix();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int width, int height) {
  glViewport(0, 0, GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height));
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluPerspective(50.0, GLdouble(width)/GLdouble(height), 1.0, 100.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
  glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
  glutCreateWindow("Transformations");

  init();
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);

  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

If you haven't done so already, try to copy/paste the example code instead, or check for any missing dlls (and check if they are in the right directories). There's definitely nothing wrong with the example code; it ran perfectly in Visual Studio.